# invalid app id when logging into facebook from custom app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I used facebook sdk and created app in facebook couple of months back. Also, I was able to access and authenticate to the app.

But not sure what happened all of a sudden I am getting `invalid App ID : app_id`.

the only difference from last time to now is ... i created new emulator now.

so what are the check list to debug this issue.

I could see many threads asking the invalid app id but none of them ended with answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether  your app is still listed in your facebook developer account. Check the ID of the app in the facebook page with that you are having now.

Comment: yes i could see the app and app id is same.
Also, I am able to get the data in graph api.

Comment: Did you find the solution i am facing the same issue